# How to use the "recovery tool" to repair a perfino h2 database?

Tags: perfino

Our Perfino server crashed recently, logging since then the ERROR shown below. (There are some clues hinting to an OutOfMemory resulting in a corrupt db.)

It is suggested: '*Possible solution: use the recovery tool*'. But neither the official perfino documentation nor the logs offer more instructions on how to proceed.

So here the question: **how to use the recovery tool?**

Stacktrace:

```
ERROR [collector] server: could not load transaction data
org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: File corrupted while reading record: "[495834] stream data key:64898 pos:11 remaining:0". Possible solution: use the recovery tool; SQL statement:
SELECT value FROM transaction_names WHERE id=? [90030-176]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:344)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:178)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:154)
    at org.h2.index.PageDataIndex.getPage(PageDataIndex.java:242)
    at org.h2.index.PageDataNode.getNextPage(PageDataNode.java:233)
    at org.h2.index.PageDataLeaf.getNextPage(PageDataLeaf.java:400)
    at org.h2.index.PageDataCursor.nextRow(PageDataCursor.java:95)
    at org.h2.index.PageDataCursor.next(PageDataCursor.java:53)
    at org.h2.index.IndexCursor.next(IndexCursor.java:278)
    at org.h2.table.TableFilter.next(TableFilter.java:361)
    at org.h2.command.dml.Select.queryFlat(Select.java:533)
    at org.h2.command.dml.Select.queryWithoutCache(Select.java:646)
    at org.h2.command.dml.Query.query(Query.java:323)
    at org.h2.command.dml.Query.query(Query.java:291)
    at org.h2.command.dml.Query.query(Query.java:37)
    at org.h2.command.CommandContainer.query(CommandContainer.java:91)
    at org.h2.command.Command.executeQuery(Command.java:197)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcPreparedStatement.executeQuery(JdbcPreparedStatement.java:109)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(NewProxyPreparedStatement.java:353)
    at com.perfino.a.f.b.a.a(ejt:70)
    at com.perfino.a.f.o.a(ejt:880)
    at com.perfino.a.f.o.a(ejt:928)
    at com.perfino.a.f.o.a(ejt:60)
    at com.perfino.a.f.aa.a(ejt:783)
    at com.perfino.a.f.o.a(ejt:847)
    at com.perfino.a.f.o.a(ejt:792)
    at com.perfino.a.f.o.a(ejt:787)
    at com.perfino.a.f.o.a(ejt:60)
    at com.perfino.a.f.ac.a(ejt:1011)
    at com.perfino.b.a.b(ejt:68)
    at com.perfino.b.a.c(ejt:82)
    at com.perfino.a.f.o.a(ejt:1006)
    at com.perfino.a.i.b.d.a(ejt:168)
    at com.perfino.a.i.b.d.b(ejt:155)
    at com.perfino.a.i.b.d.b(ejt:52)
    at com.perfino.a.i.b.d.a(ejt:45)
    at com.perfino.a.i.a.b.a(ejt:94)
    at com.perfino.a.c.a.b(ejt:105)
    at com.perfino.a.c.a.a(ejt:37)
    at com.perfino.a.c.c.run(ejt:57)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Answer (score 10):

*Notice: I couldn't recover my database with the procedure described below. I'm still keeping this post as reference, as the probability of a successful recovery will depend on how broken the database is, and there is no evidence that this procedure is invalid.*

---

Perfino uses by default the [H2 Database Engine](http://www.h2database.com/javadoc/) as its persistence storage. H2 has a [recovery tool](http://www.h2database.com/javadoc/org/h2/tools/Recover.html) and a [run script tool](http://www.h2database.com/javadoc/org/h2/tools/RunScript.html) to import sql statements:

```sh
# 1. Create a dump of the current database using the tool [1]
# This tool creates a 'config.h2.sql' and a 'perfino.h2.sql' db dump
cd ${PERFINO_DATA_DIR}
java -cp ${PATH_TO_H2_LIB}/h2*.jar org.h2.tools.Recover

# 2. Rename the corrupt database file to e.g. *bkp
mv perfino.h2.db perfino.h2.db.bkp

# 3. Import the dump from step 1, ignoring errors
java -cp ${PATH_TO_H2_LIB}/h2*.jar \
     org.h2.tools.RunScript \
     -url jdbc:h2:${PERFINO_DATA_DIR}/db/perfino \
     -script perfino.h2.sql -checkResults
```

<sup>[1]: Perfino includes a version of the `h2.jar` under `${PERFINO_INSTALL_DIR}/lib/common/h2.jar`. You could of course download the [official jar](http://www.h2database.com/html/download.html) and try with it, but in my case, I could only restore the database with the jar supplied with perfino.</sup>

---

This failed for me with a

> `Exception in thread "main" org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Feature not supported: "Restore page store recovery SQL script can only be restored to a PageStore file"`.

If this happens to you, try:

```sh
# 1. Delete database and mv files
cd ${PERFINO_DATA_DIR}
rm perfino.h2.db perfino.mv.db

# 2. Create a PageStore database manually
touch perfino.h2.db

# 3. try with MV_STORE=FALSE on the url [2]
java -cp ${PATH_TO_H2_LIB}/h2*.jar \
     org.h2.tools.RunScript \
     -url jdbc:h2:${PERFINO_DATA_DIR}/db/perfino;MV_STORE=FALSE \
     -checkResults \
     -continueOnError
```

<sub>[2]: force h2 to recreate a pagestore db instead of the new storage engine (See [this thread in metabase](https://github.com/metabase/metabase/issues/3560#issuecomment-253638208))</sub>

Comment: Very helpful. got it working with h2-1.4.200

Answer (score 2):

I found this article trying to repair a Confluence internal h2 database and this worked for me. Here's a shell script as a [gist on my GitHub](https://gist.github.com/AlmostGosu/6220fbf8adb7f46044e4578f67f3a28e) with what I did - you'll have to adjust for your environment.